# Binding collections to DataGridView in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, datagridview, winforms

I'm trying to bind a collection to a DataGridView. As it turns out it's impossible for the user to edit anything in this DataGridView although EditMode is set to EditOnKeystrokeOrF2.
Here is the simplified code:

```
public Supplies()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   List<string> l = new <string>();
   l.Add("hello");
   this.SuppliesDataGridView.DataSource = l;
}
```

It also doesn't work when I change the collection type to SortableBindingList, Dictionary or even use a BindingSource.

What can be wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

For me the following method works as expected:

- Open your form (usercontrol, etc.) with the designer
- Add a BindingSource to your form
- Select the BindingSource in your form and open the properties page
- Select the DataSource property and click on the down arrow
- Click on *Add project data source*
- Select *Object*
- Select the object type you wish to handle

  - This should be the type that will be handled by your collection, not the CustomCollection itself!
- Show the available data sources by selecting from the MenuBar *Data - Show Data Sources*
- Drag and Drop your ItemType from the DatasSources on your form
- Go into the code of your form and bind your CustomCollection to the BindingSource

  ```
      var cc = new CustomCollection();
      bindingSource1.DataSource = cc;
  ```

**Remarks**:
The DataGridView is just the last part in your chain to (dis)allow changing, adding and removing objects from your list (or CustomCollection). There is also a property `AllowNew` within the BindingSource and the `ICollection` interface has a property `IsReadOnly` which must be set to `false` to allow editing. Last but not least, the properties of your class within the collection must have a public setter method to allow changing of a value.

Comment: I've done what you did, but when I try to add a new object to the list the DataGridView doesn't refresh, although the list itself is correct, and casting the binding's DataSource returns a correct list too.

Comment: If you manipulate the collection (add, remove, insert, clear), the binding source must be informed about that change. Either you implement `IBindingList` and raise the ListChanged event when needed; use instead of your normal collection the `BindingList<T>` or you call `bindingSource.ResetBindings(false)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    public class CustomCollection { public string Value { get; set; } }

    public Supplies()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<CustomCollection> l = new List<CustomCollection> { new CustomCollection { Value = "hello" } };
        this.SuppliesDataGridView.DataSource = l;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Once you've set the DataSource property you'll then want to fire off the `DataBind()` method.</strike>

```
this.SuppliesDataGridView.DataSource = l;
this.SuppliesDataGridView.DataBind();
```

**UPDATE:**

As you rightly pointed out in the comments, the DataBind() method doesn't exist for this control.

This link might provide some helpful information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fbk67b6z%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

Comment: There is no such method in SuppliesDataGridView.